# How do I change a an element's style without triggering a re-render in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm developing a video playback app using Electron.  One of my requirements is a seamless transition between back-to-back videos.  Due to load times, I can't really achieve that with a single video element.  So I've gone with two video elements, laid out one over the other.

In regular HTML I can make this work fairly well.  I fiddle with the z-index, and the two videos snap back and forth.  Problem is that React doesn't seem to like me fiddling with the z-index.

I have tried several variations on the following three pieces of code:

```
this.frontPlayer.current.style = { ...this.frontPlayer.current.style, zIndex: "2" }
this.frontPlayer.current.style.zIndex = 2
this.frontPlayer.current.style.setProperty('zIndex', 2)
```

In each case, when I use console.log to examine the result, the style element breaks down.  I have log statements bracketing the change, and I can see it go from a a style declaration that includes a z-index change, to a blank style index.

Answer (score 0):

And having failed to post the question, the next morning I realize the problem.  CSSStyleDeclaration objects aren't a React element, they're a native CSS element.  While they have a zIndex property, they're meant to be updated via setProperty, using a standard css label of 'z-index'.

```
this.frontPlayer.current.style.setProperty('z-index', 2)
```

Comment: I need to do something similar to what you did with a bunch of iFrames that we want to keep "hydrated" and then just bring one to the top and keep/push the others to be back. I don't quite understand what you're doing here. The component does actually re-render, right? But the elements don't? What about the element with the updated zIndex property, doesn't it have to rerender?

Comment: @HK1 other way around: the (React) components *don't* re-render, because I haven't changed anything React recognizes.  The HTML *elements* just change their styling, causing the browser to update how it displays things.